# Clone Opportunity. How make the difference between Clone and Cone with related in apex code?

Tags: apex, trigger, clone

I want to use Clone button in opportunity. There is also a Clone with related.

I want to create a trigger in apex which can have different behaviour deending if user click on Clone or Clone with related.
How can I can catch the clone method?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you simply cannot differentiate the two cases. Related records must be created AFTER the parent record creation has been finalised, since they require the parent's ID. As such the initial clone creation will look identical in both cases. The only solution would be to replace the default actions in the UI with your own and provide the differentiating logic in the action processing.